# Turbolinks with request loading

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In my vue.js 2.0 project I use Turbolinks.

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        mixins: [TurbolinksAdapter],
        data() {
            return {
                showModal: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So my question is how would I detect a `post` request. Before I used turbolinks I had this:

```
$("form").submit(() => {
    $("#submit").addClass("is-loading");
    return true;
});
```

But that's obviously not working anymore because it does not refresh the entire page anymore.

Any Idea how I could get this to working again?

Comment: What is triggering the `post` request? You probably could put the `$("#submit").addClass("is-loading");` code in the function that triggers the request.

Comment: Just a form post request: `<button id="submit" class="button is-primary> etc.. `